# I need to prevent users from altering settings of my app

Tags: android

I want to prevent users altering settings of my app by throwing up a splash screen to block interactions whenever they go into the device settings and open the settings page for my app.

Here's a video of another app that does this: https://inversatechnosoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/WhatsApp-Video-2021-03-05-at-7.40.24-AM.mp4

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible (at least for apps that aren't part of the system image), for good reason: that's the sort of thing malware does to take over a system.

Even if you could do that, that isn't sufficient: an app could also be uninstalled from the launcher, or other apps.  You could make it harder through various tricks, but ultimately the user could simply reboot the device into safe mode and do it there.

The only cases where you could have this level of control are [managed devices](https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation#managing_company-owned_devices) or within a work profile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an incredibly clean way to do this, but you could start a service which regularly checks the foreground task.

You can then use the `ActivityManager` to get a list of all running app processes with [`ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses()) and then check their [`importance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo#importance) against `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`.

Comment: Did you check the reference video ? We need to detect when the user goes to settings and clicks on our app

Comment: Won't work if the user reboots into safe mode (their app won't start), unless they're part of the system image.